# URL setting for tomcat project

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, url

I am currently working on a Java EE Eclipse tomcat project. 
Currently I can access my work by entering `http: //localhost:8080/`
What should I do if I want to access it by entering something like `http: //test.com/`
And what else should I do to make it go to mobile page when entering something like `http://mtest.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you might be hosting the application (server in the basement or shared hosting with a hosting service such as Huroku, openshift etc), you need to register your domain name (in this case test.com) with a Domain Name company (GoDaddy).

Once that is done you would want to point your domain name to the ip address where you are hosting your application. If its a server in your basement, you might need to do some port forwarding on your router, but most importantly the domain name needs to point to a STATIC IP ADDRESS, not a dynamic one.

If hosting with companies such as huroku or openshift, figure out the ipaddress of your application and point your domain name to it.

As for m.test.com sub-domain, you need to setup a SUB DOMAIN under your main domain, and it can be pointed to your mobile page.

Hopefully your application is coded to be MOBILE RESPONSIVE, depending on the platform pulling up your application, it should present the best possible view for that device/platform.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `/private/etc/hosts` file on your mac and there add a line like below

> 127.0.0.1       test.com

Also, make sure your application runs on port 80 rather than port 8080 as default web port resolved is 80 i.e. it needs not to be added to url when port no. is 80 for http. 443 is the port for https.

Similarly, you could have different ips mapped to your mobile app and web app urls.

One good way of doing it is by using virtual box locally.

**Install virtual box** > **Load your mobile application there** by running another os instance and tomcat instance > **Enable cross communication between your virtual machine and osx**.(To verify it try ssh access to your virtual machine). > **In your `/private/etc/hosts` of osx add virtual machine's ip** with mobile apps url.

Example hosts file would be like below,

```
  127.0.0.1             test.com 
  192.168.0.256       m.test.com
```

Though this solution might not align much to real time scenario but could be helpful for local environments.

This is what I'm doing for myself.

Now, for redirect you don't need to bother. Though there might be a scenario when a user enters web-app url from mobile, then you could add a script like below to your pages or use apache redirects which I'm not much familiar with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (screen.width <= 600) {
    window.location = "http://m.test.com";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: why downvoted? Please let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote it

Comment: Well then if I start another project, would't it be accessible with the same name?

Comment: This is a web application, are you going to edit /etc/hosts for every client?  Also your explanation for setting port numbers is very lacking in detail.

Comment: I guess he is doing it locally. Otherwise he could need rewrite rule in apache .htaccess. If he is doing it on his test server even then he would be having different ips and hence each ip could be mapped to a url. Everything talked here is in terms of local environment.